# What is the best way to automatically validate requests using Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I would like to use Typescript interfaces to easily validate backend requests. Is there a way to make it happen? Example of what I would love to do:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'

interface AuthenticateParams {
    email: string
    password: string
}

type AuthenticationRequest = Request & {body: AuthenticateParams}

const authenticate = async (req: AuthenticationRequest, res: Response) => {
    if (typeof req.body !== AuthenticateParams) res.status(400).send('Invalid body')

    // DO STUFF
    let stuff

    res.status(200).send(stuff)
}

export default authenticate
```

Comment: Interfaces don't exist at runtime.

Comment: Typescript doesn't provide this functionality.

Comment: Closest thing I can think of is leveraging [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) but that is outside of TypeScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are TypeScript "Interfaces" also input validators? (In other Modules or User Requests)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988124/are-typescript-interfaces-also-input-validators-in-other-modules-or-user-req)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE 2022:

I stumbled upon [Runtypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/runtypes) and I think it is quite a cool solution. And when you think of it, quite an obvious one: You use a solution in the middle that automatically gives you correct types and a possibility to check the validity. It's much better than trying to work from types to validating, since interfaces don't exist in runtime as was said multiple times.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Yeah, I understand that interfaces don't exist in runtime. I created this solution, that validates my input and gives me type errors, when I need them. I think my title was bit misleading, so I'll also change the title to "What is the best way to automatically validate requests using Typescript".

The idea is to force me to write a simple schema for each interface I wish to use to validate a backend endpoint. Also, in order to minimize the possibility to human errors, it is important that my linter type checks the `validatorObject`.

validateParams.ts:

```
const validateParams: (targetObject: any, validatorObject: any) => boolean = (targetObject, validatorObject) => {
    if (typeof targetObject !== typeof validatorObject) return false
    if (typeof targetObject === 'object') {
        let validObject = true
        if (Array.isArray(targetObject)) {
            for (let subObject of targetObject) {
                validObject = validObject && validateParams(subObject, validatorObject[0])
            }
        } else {
            for (let key of Object.keys(validatorObject)) {
                if (typeof targetObject[key] === 'object') validObject = validObject && validateParams(targetObject[key], validatorObject[key])
                if (typeof targetObject[key] !== typeof validatorObject[key]) validObject = false
            }
        }
        return validObject
    }
    return true
}

export default validateParams
```

authenticate.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import validateParams from "./validateParams"

interface AuthenticateParams {
    email: string
    password: string
}

const validatorObject: AuthenticateParams = {
    email: 'string',
    password: 'string'
}

type AuthenticationRequest = Request & {body: AuthenticateParams}

const authenticate = async (req: AuthenticationRequest, res: Response) => {
    if (!validateParams(req.body, validatorObject)) res.status(400).send('Invalid body')

    // DO STUFF
    let stuff

    res.status(200).send(stuff)
}

export default authenticate
```

updateUser.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import validateParams from "./validateParams"

interface UpdateUserParams {
    name: string
    products: {
        name: string
        price: number
    }[]
}

const validatorObject: UpdateUserParams = {
    name: 'string',
    products: [{name: 'string', number: 0}]
}

type AuthenticationRequest = Request & {body: UpdateUserParams}

const updateUser = async (req: UpdateUserParams, res: Response) => {
    if (!validateParams(req.body, validatorObject)) res.status(400).send('Invalid body')

    // DO STUFF
    let stuff

    res.status(200).send(stuff)
}

export default updateUser
```

This is not the most beautiful solution, but I like that it validates my requests automatically and also gives me errors, if I forget to update my validatorObject. But yeah, it would be awesome to get the Typescript interfaces in runtime.

Answer (score 3):

If you also maintaining openapi documentation, you can validate the request using [express-openapi-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-openapi-validator). It is also available for fastify and Koa

Comment: This is awesome, though note that if you still want transpile-time type checking as well, without keeping OpenAPI and TS type definitions manually in sync, you need another library to convert OpenAPI -> TS. I haven't been able to find a _great_ solution for this, but https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-typescript seems to work well enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. Interfaces only exist when compiling and checking your code, but TypeScript has no runtime.

Once your TypeScript code is compiled, it becomes normal JavaScript. And JavaScript has no concept of interfaces, so it can't check that.

You basically need to write your own function to verify the interface by, for example, checking that specific fields exist on the object, or that it's an instance of a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces in typescript are purely a compile-time construct. What you are trying to do is dynamically check the type of the body.

You can achieve what you want with a schema validator.

Comment: It would be immensely useful to have something that integrates json schema validation and typescript definitions. So that you do not have to define the "type" twice: preventing bugs when updating.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best helper for checking property keys, while being integrated with typescript. There is a change that this could be extended recursively.

```
function hasKeys<T, K extends string | number | symbol>(
    obj: T, 
    keys: K | K[]
): obj is T & { [P in K]: unknown } {
    return Array.isArray(keys) ? keys.every(k => k in obj) : keys in obj;
}
```

```
declare const obj: unknown;

if(typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null) {
    if("prop" in obj) {
        // Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)
        let x = obj.prop;
    }

    if(hasKeys(obj, "prop")) {
        let x = obj.prop;
    }

    if(hasKeys(obj, ["prop1", "prop2"])) {
        let x = obj.prop1;
        let y = obj.prop2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [this package](https://express-validator.github.io/docs) for a long time.

#### A quote from his official website:

express-validator is a set of [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) middlewares that wraps the extensive collection of validators and sanitizers offered by [validator.js](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js).

It allows you to combine them in many ways so that you can validate and sanitize your express requests, and offers tools to determine if the request is valid or not, which data was matched according to your validators, and so on.