# Typescript User-Defined typeguards for validating any to type

Tags: typescript, types, typeguards

I'm new to Typescript, and i have stumbled upon a problem, that i can't seem to find a good solution for.

In my project i need to validate a http-request body to be able to work with it. Since it is a http-request body it needs to have the type: any.

I have made an interface for the type i want the request body to have.

```
interface IdealRequestBody{
    seed: string,
    categoryShares: CategoryShares
}
```

The only solution i've found for validating if the http-request body is of type: IdealRequestBody is using User-Defined typeguards like the following:

```
isRequestBody(requestBody : any) : requestBody is IdealRequestBody{
        return requestBody.seed !== undefined && 
        requestBody.categoryShares !== undefined &&
        typeof(requestBody.seed) === 'string' &&
        isCategoryShares(requestBody.categoryShares);
}
```

My problem with this approach is, that by validating a type like this, i write a lot of redundant code. I essentially define the type i want two times. This approach is also less error proof, because it is easy for me to forget a check, or define a check in the wrong way. Isn't there any way for me to let Typescript handle the type guards for me, or is this approach really the only and best way to do it?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Try to eliminate the any type up thru your code

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly this isn't possible, because a http-request body can be anything, i have no control over what people may put into their http-request bodies.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://www.npmjs.com/package/runtypes
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58861115/what-is-the-best-way-to-automatically-validate-requests-using-typescript